# Storing user information in multiple collections using same id

Tags: mongodb, database-design

I have three collections. **User**, **Address**, and **Workplace**. To maintain my data easily, I have used the _id of User collection as the ids of Location and Workplace collections. For example, if I want to store a user's information, I will store it like this -

A document in User collection

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("605d6d93e1715f3650a8e8c2"),
  name: A
}
```

A document in Address collection

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("605d6d93e1715f3650a8e8c2"),
  address: District B
}
```

A document in Workplace collection

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("605d6d93e1715f3650a8e8c2"),
  workplace: District C
}
```

Is it a good idea to use the same id? If no, what problems I might face in the future?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: should be fine i think

Comment: The way data is stored depends upon your use case. See [Data Model Design](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/index.html).

Comment: What will you do for multiple addresses? like previous address. Mongodb will support this. but not sure if it is a good idea though.